# Copy column value from one dataframe to another based on id in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to copy `Name` from `df2` into `df1` where `ID` is common between both dataframes.

df1:

```
ID    Name 

1     A
2     B
4     C
16    D
7     E
```

df2:

```
ID    Name 

1     X
2     Y
7     Z
```

Expected Output:

```
ID    Name 

1     X
2     Y
4     C
16    D
7     Z
```

I have tried like this, but it didn't worked. I am not able to understand how to assign value here. I am assigning `=df2['Name']` which is wrong.

```
for i in df2["ID"].tolist():
    df1['Name'].loc[(df1['ID'] == i)] = df2['Name']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `update`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('ID')
df1.update(df2.set_index('ID'))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1
Out[476]: 
   ID Name
0   1    X
1   2    Y
2   4    C
3  16    D
4   7    Z
```

Comment: @ben-yo Thanks, It is working but do you know why it is converting `int` columns to `float`?

Comment: @Rajnishkumar that is due to update will have some `NaN`

Comment: This is faster than my `df.loc` assignment solution. Is it because `update` aligns the indices with [`reindex_like`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.1.1/pandas/core/frame.py#L6366)?

Comment: @wwii yes, reindex_like ~

Answer (score 1):

If the order of rows does not matter, then concatenate two dfs and drop_duplicates will achieve the result,

```
df2.append(df1).drop_duplicates(subset='ID')
```

Comment: I didn't set 'ID' as index, 'ID' a column

Answer (score 0):

another solution would be,

```
s = df1["Name"]
df1.loc[:,"Name"]=df1["ID"].map(df2.set_index("ID")["Name"].to_dict()).fillna(s)
```

o/P:

```
   ID Name
0   1    X
1   2    Y
2   4    C
3  16    D
4   7    Z
```

Answer (score 0):

One more for consideration

```
df,dg = df1,df2
df = df.set_index('ID')
dg = dg.set_index('ID')
df.loc[dg.index,:] = dg               # All columns
#df.loc[dg.index,'Name'] = dg.Name    # Single column
df = df.reset_index()

>>> df
   ID Name
0   1    X
1   2    Y
2   4    C
3  16    D
4   7    Z
```

Or for a single column (index for both is 'ID'